# Golang variable struct field

Tags: go

This may require reflection but I'm not sure. I am trying to loop through an array of required fields in a struct. If any of those fields are nil I want to throw an error essentially. I've got the basic form down but I realized I don't know how in Go to pass a struct field name via a variabel

imagine you have a struct called EmailTemplate and it has a field called template_id

In this case I want to know if EmailTemplate.TemplateId is nil

emailDef.Fields is a string array ["TemplateId"]

I want to check if those fields are in the EmailTemplate struct and if they are nil

```
    for field := range emailDef.Fields {
        fmt.Println(emailDef.Fields[field])
        if EmailTemplate.[emailDef.Fields[field]] == nil {
            missingField := true
        }         
    }
```

is along the lines of what I am thinking but I know that is wrong as a struct isn't an array. emailDef.Fields[field] would be equivalent to TemplateId

Answer (score 1):

Your loop stuff doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me so I'll give a general example with a single field in a string called `field`. If you have a slice or array of fields you want to check for then you'll want to range over that using the current value for `field`.

```
import "reflect"

st := reflect.TypeOf(EmailTemplate)
v, ok := st.FieldByName(field)
if ok {
    // field existed on EmailTemplate, now check if it's nil
    if v.IsNil() {
        // the field field on instance EmailTemplate was nil, do something
    }
}
```

Now assuming you have a list of fields you need to check are all non-nil, then just add a loop like so;

```
for field := range requiredFields {
    st := reflect.TypeOf(EmailTemplate)
    v, ok := st.FieldByName(field)
    if ok {
        // field existed on EmailTemplate, now check if it's nil
        if v.IsNil() {
          // the field field on instance EmailTemplate was nil, do something
          // maybe raise error since the field was nil
    } else {
        //the field wasn't found at all, probably time to raise an error
    }
  }
}
```

reflect package docs are here; https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/